# Update work item relations/links in VS Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the VSTS API to remove all parent links on items, and set those parents as related items.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-work-items

I do not fully understand how the "Path" needed to remove relations work – I am getting inconsistent results where sometimes it works, sometimes not (so, im clearly doing it wrong)

I am making an assumption that its simply the **order** returned by the API. So, for example:

- Index[0] item
- Index[1] item
- Index[2] item <- this is the one I want to remove, so I use index 2

  ```
      public void RemoveParentLink(int pathIndex, int itemToUpdate, string link)
  {

      JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

      patchDocument.Add(
         new JsonPatchOperation()
         {
             Operation = Operation.Remove,
             Path = $"/relations/{pathIndex}"

         }
      );

      WorkItem result = witClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, itemToUpdate).Result;

  }
  ```

The documentation states that Path is:

Path to the value you want to add, replace, remove, or test.
For a specific relation, use "relations/Id".
For all relations, use "/relations/-".

Index is NOT the Id of course, but how do I get the relation/Id exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Using GetWorkItemAsync or GetWorkItemsAsync with WorkItemExpand.Relations parameter to get linked work items.

```
Var workItem=witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(id: [work item id], expand: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItemExpand.Relations).Result.
```

Then the index is the index of relations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The '`id`' in the `'/relation/id'` path is a index in fact. You retrieve the work item definition, then the `'id'` is the index of the link in the `'relations'` array. Hence your assumption is right.

Evidence: given a work item with 2 links, if you try to delete/modify id >= 2 it will answer with:

> { "$id": "1", "innerException": null, "message": "Index out of range
>   for path /relations/2.", "typeName":
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.PatchOperationFailedException,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "typeKey":
>   "PatchOperationFailedException", "errorCode": 0, "eventId": 3000 }

0 and 1 as `id` work just fine instead.

I may be wrong, but I could guess that you could get an error when using the `'replace'` operation before the `'add'` operation. For example you need to add a `'comment'` inside the `'attributes'` of a link before modifying (i.e. 'replace' operation) its value.